# I am trying to run an Anderson Darling Test and this keeps happening (see screenshot). how do i solve this?

Tags: r

All cases are complete in my dataset but the error message states i have selected undefined columns. I have tried multiple ways of specifying that none of my data contains missing values but none worked...

Sorry i am a very new to R and have probably set this out all wrong !

[image]

Comment: According to that package's documentation, `ad.test()` takes a vector. You're feeding it a dataframe. Try `ad.test(Data1[,1])`.

Comment: Thanks so much ! this worked. Do you know if "ad.test(Data1[,1])" means that all cases are complete in my dataset ?

Comment: No, it literally means "plug in the first variable of that dataset into that function."